# Impossible to access My Apps in iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect, ibooks

I recently bought a iOS Development License and I want to publish an app with iTunes Connect, but in the past, I tried to upload a book made with iBooks Author, and now, when I connect to the iTunes Connect site, I can only access to My Books, but not to My Apps!

How delete My Books and access to My Apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple doesn't allow you to use the same iTunes Connect account for both iBooks and the App Store. You'll need to create a new account to upload apps.

From [here](https://www.apple.com/itunes/working-itunes/sell-content/books/book-faq.html):

> Do I need an Apple ID to offer my books on the iBooks Store?
>
> Yes, to use iTunes Connect, you must have an Apple ID with a valid credit card on file. You can use the same Apple ID you use to sign in to your iTunes Store account. If you don’t have an Apple ID, you can create one using iTunes by clicking Sign In and then Create Apple ID.
>
> If you are selling other content types on iTunes (such as apps, music, TV shows, or movies) and have another iTunes Connect account, you can’t use the same Apple ID for the iBooks Store.

Comment: Not sure whether this solution is still valid. Apple Store Connect app, which can be used to access the information of apps, has been release by apple.

Answer (score 0):

You can use App Store Connect to access mobile Apps. You can use the same Apple ID to for iBooks and Apps. For iBooks, you should still use iTunesConnect.